# How can I use the same ViewController from a storyboard with different sizes?

Tags: ios

I want to use a view controller from a storyboard twice (DRY!). However, in one case I'd like it to be full screen, and in other I'd like it to be roughly 3/4 of the screen (within another VC). How can I reuse it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great library for that. I didn't create it but I have used it: https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController

here is a partial snippet

```
MZFormSheetSegue *formSheetSegue = (MZFormSheetSegue *)segue;
        MZFormSheetController *formSheet = formSheetSegue.formSheetController;
        formSheet.transitionStyle = MZFormSheetTransitionStyleBounce;
        formSheet.shouldCenterVertically = YES;
        formSheet.cornerRadius = 0;
        formSheet.presentedFormSheetSize = CGSizeMake(290, 290);
```

So the idea is that, when you segue, if you want full size then segue normally. If you want smaller size, use as I show in the snippet above. Read the readme and the example.

Instead of going on and one, I am leaving it to you to ask more question if you need further help as you try out the git project.